# Build Angular 7 application including only some sub-applications

Tags: angular, angular-cli

my problem is the following. I have an Angular 7 application with Angular CLI and multiple sub-applications which give the parent app different features.

I want to be able to generate builds having none of the sub-applications included, some of them or all of them. I would have to choose this in compilation time. This way I can deliver different builds to different customers and the code delivered only includes the necessary features, saving on build time, size and making sure they don't get the features they are not supposed to get.

A similar scenario would be creating a new app as follows

```
ng new main-app
cd main-app
ng g application sub-app1
ng g application sub-app2
ng g application sub-app3
```

And then generating a build that only includes the main-app, sub-app1, and sub-app3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try `ng build <project> [options]` as sated at https://angular.io/cli/build? Where the <project> is "The name of the project to build. Can be an app or a library."

Comment: A little more clarification would be helpful. Are you taking the output js files and emailing them to clients or are you talking about what the different clients get from your server? ClientA goes to your server and they only get files for sub-app1, ClientB also goes to your server and only get files for sub-app2? If so it would sound like lazy module loading and possibly some route guards would do the trick. Please clarify.

Comment: Sure, I'll clarify a little bit more. I don't want to build just one of the sub-apps alone, I want to build the main-app and a subgroup of the sub-apps to generate the dist files that will get shipped to the client. Lazy loading doesn't solve my issue as the code of the functionalities I don't want the user to get will still end in it's server. What I want is a build command that will build the files of the main-app together with a subgroup of the sub-apps.

Comment: @Ivan have you solved this? I need exactly the same thing.

Comment: @user2132190 I did not solved, ended up discarding the idea... Sorry for the late reply